Deep filtering not filtering
I have an Highlight collection that have a highlighted component with a list of campaigns (relations). Each campaign have a list of countries (relations).
I'm trying to filter my Highlight collection based on a given country. I should only have highlight with highlighted valued with campaigns that have the country listed as one of their countries.
I'm using the REST API to filter my collection, I have something like this:
const query = {
  locale: locale.toLowerCase(),
  filters: {
    type: {
      $eq: type,
    },
    highlighted: {
      campaign: {
        countries: {
          name: {
            $eq: country,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  populate: [
    'highlighted',
    'highlighted.start_at',
    'highlighted.end_at',
    'highlighted.tag',
    'highlighted.image',
    'highlighted.logo',
    'highlighted.campaign',
    'highlighted.campaign.countries',
    'highlighted.campaign.campaign_rewards',
    'highlighted.campaign.campaign_rewards.Boosted',
    'highlighted.campaign.image_small',
    'highlighted.campaign.image_large',
  ],
};

qs.stringify(queryObject, { encodeValuesOnly: true });

Any filters that could add to the campaign relation is not working.
I have not seen any limit on the depth level for filtering.
Also I've checked that all the permissions are set correctly.
I could narrow it down to not have the campaign, but the highlighted sill got populated with an empty campaign array with this query:
{
  locale: locale.toLowerCase(),
  filters: {
    type: {
      $eq: type,
    },
  },
  populate: {
    highlighted: {
      populate: {
        tag: true,
        image: true,
        campaign: {
          filters: {
            countries: {
              name: {
                $eq: country,
              },
            },
            name: {
              $notNull: true,
            },
          },
          populate: {
            image_small: true,
            image_large: true,
            countries: true,
            campaign_rewards: {
              populate: ['Boosted'],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};



I don't think you allowed to filter on nested relations like that, instead you have to query campaign separately.

So actually you can, but since the highlighted component must have a campaign, when the campaign get filtered out you only get null. But it wont strip out the highlighted component. May be a limitation on repeatable component
